# Reading every file in a directory for a keyword

Tags: ruby

Currently, I'm trying to learn how to read every file in a directory and look for a persific keyword such as "score"

Heres what I've gotten so far

```
    File.open("C:/Users/Cam/Desktop/Warmup/Warmup_scores", "r") do |f|
  f.each_line do |line|
    if line.include? "Score" 
        puts line
    end
  end
end
```

This works for single files but trying to make it work for an entire directory is a little tricky, any help?

Comment: A quick way of doing that for one file is to use [Enumerable#grep](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-grep): `puts File.foreach(file_name).grep(/\bScore\b/)`. `\b` is a *word break* which prevents words such as `"Scoreboard"` from being matched. This does have the disadvantage that it produces a temporary array, but since you are printing, rather than saving, lines, I assume the files are only modest in size. Regardless of your approach you should consider using [IO::foreach](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/IO.html#method-c-foreach) for reading files line-by-line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way. https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Dir.html

```
Dir["C:/Users/Cam/Desktop/Warmup/*"].each do |filename|
  File.open(filename) do |f|
    f.each_line do |line|
      if line.include? "Score" 
        puts line
      end
    end
  end
end
```

You can even search in subdirectories

```
Dir["C:/Users/Cam/Desktop/Warmup/**/*"]
```

or a particular pattern

```
Dir["C:/Users/Cam/Desktop/Warmup/*.txt"]
```

Comment: I get an error message when I try that:
"test.rb:3:in `block (2 levels) in <main>': undefined local variable or method "`f " for main:Object (NameError)"
I'm still learning about the File and Dir objects so I really dont know what to do D: